# Managing Angular 5 layout with a service

Tags: angular5

In an angular5 application, I have various sections of my page layout that I would like to control through an angular service. For example, I have a sidenav component that displays when a value is set to open, and I would like to be able to toggle it from any component I'd like.

My initial thought was that it would be nice if I could bind the `open` value to a variable in a `LayoutService` I would create, and the `LayoutService` would contain a `toggle()` method that would toggle the value and cause the sidenav to open/close. I could then inject my `LayoutService` into any component I'd like and control various parts of my layout.

Any idea whether this is possible and how I could go about doing this? I thought it might be possible using an `EventEmitter` or something, but I was wondering whether there was a simpler way and I'd rather not use redux.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lj7gsz

Here's a side-bar you can open and close using simple rxjs objects.

In the side-bar service, I've created a BehaviorSubject that you can pass boolean values to and I also exposed an Observable, which will emit every time a new value is passed to that subject.

By subscribing to that observable (I've used the async pipe to subscribe for me), my side-bar component will know when other components wish to open or close the side-bar. All the other components need to do is inject the service and call the service's open or close methods.

It's not perfect, but I feel it's definitely better than using event emitters as they were never made to be used in services.

Hopefully this is helpful.